# How do I store whois result to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I do have a PHP script for searching whois info of any domains. I want store that info to a MySQL table to use it later. How do I do it?

Below is the result which I need to store in MySQL table and engine is MyISAM
I have tried text method but no success...

```
Registrant:
        Dns Admin
        Google Inc.
        Please contact contact-admin@google.com 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway
         Mountain View CA 94043
        US
        dns-admin@google.com +1.6502530000 Fax: +1.6506188571

    Domain Name: google.com

        Registrar Name: Markmonitor.com
        Registrar Whois: whois.markmonitor.com
        Registrar Homepage: http://www.markmonitor.com

    Administrative Contact:
        DNS Admin
        Google Inc.
        1600 Amphitheatre Parkway
         Mountain View CA 94043
        US
        dns-admin@google.com +1.6506234000 Fax: +1.6506188571
    Technical Contact, Zone Contact:
        DNS Admin
        Google Inc.
        2400 E. Bayshore Pkwy
         Mountain View CA 94043
        US
        dns-admin@google.com +1.6503300100 Fax: +1.6506181499

    Created on..............: 1997-09-15.
    Expires on..............: 2020-09-13.
    Record last updated on..: 2012-01-29.

    Domain servers in listed order:

    ns4.google.com
    ns1.google.com
    ns2.google.com
    ns3.google.com




MarkMonitor is the Global Leader in Online Brand Protection.

Domain Management
MarkMonitor Brand Protection™
MarkMonitor AntiPiracy™
MarkMonitor AntiFraud™
Professional and Managed Services

Visit MarkMonitor at www.markmonitor.com
Contact us at 1 (800) 745-9229
In Europe, at +44 (0) 203 206 2220
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you've written so far?

Comment: Do you have a MySQL table created already and do you just need help with the queries, or do you want the table structure created too?

Comment: [did you read the manual ?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

Comment: Which whois info you want to store?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to my understanding, if you want to save info with then take db structure as:

```
whois_table
{
id (num)(pk)
ip (varchar)
info(long text)
}
```

Assume you have info like: http://www.whois.net/whois/facebook.com

$ip = IP who's whois info to be inserted
$info = whois info of ip

```
INSERT INTO whois_table (ip, info ) values ($ip, $info);
```

Comment: I would better use `INT` field type to store IPs.

Comment: @hookman: I assumed ip stored is of characers(i.e facebook.com). Though for storing ip like 192.168.12.123 require varchar because of dots.

Comment: [INET_ATON](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton), [INET_NTOA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa).

Comment: You're going to have to [escape those variables properly](http://bobby-tables.com/php).